# hover event with jquery not going back to original state

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html:

```
  <div class="sub-service">
    <div class="sub-service__image">
      <a href="#">
        <figure>
          <img width="100%" height="auto" src="https://dummyimage.com/300"> 
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-service__content">
      <h2><a href="#" title="What happens when I have started trading?">eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint </a></h2>
      <p>uis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id esuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sub-service__footer">
      <a href="#">Read More <span style="width:30px">
      </span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the following js:

```
var $h2height = $('.sub-service__content h2').filter(function() {
  return $(this).height() >= 30;
});

$h2height.parent().parent().hover(function() {
  $h2height.parent().css("transform","translateY(-105px)");
});
```

When the top parent element 'sub-service' is hovered, I am trying to modify the css of the h2 parent ('sub-service__content') when the h2 is two lines, (higher than 30px). When this is hovered, the top parent 'sub-service', it works, but when is not hovered anymore it doesn't back to the original state. What I am doing wrong? :/

I have created a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgOmpK

(the middle element is an example of what I am trying to do but when the h2 is two lines)

Thanks,

Comment: something like this ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxNKdm , would it not be much easier just to use css?

Answer (score 0):

the problem in you code is that you didn't define a function to get to the original state , try using the

> ```
> $h2height.parent().parent().mouseleave(function() {
>  $h2height.parent().css("transform","translateY(+105px)"); );
> });
> ```

Comment: Oh yeah it works now.  But for some reason when you hover it applies the effect to all the elements with two lines in the h2 :/

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgOmpK

Comment: then you just need to set the effect only on the element you need to get back in place, if you found my answer helpful can you accept it as an answer ?